# How to calculate the percent in dynamically row in ng-repeat using angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new in angular js , just Need to find error items for each row.How to do that.I am adding the row by using add1() function.It should be calculated for each row.

```
inputs: nobot(ng-model),err.bot(ng-model) for each row.
output: err.eper(ng-model) for each row.

<td><input type="text" ng-model="nobot" name="nobot"></td>
    <tr ng-repeat="err in error.items">
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="err.bot" id="b1" name="r5[]" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" ng-model="err.eper" id="b2" name="r6[]" ng-value="d4()"></td>
        <td <a href ng-click="remove1(item)">X</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><a href ng-click="add1()">+</a></td>
      </tr>
```

Please help me out.Please let me know if any problems to understand the Question.

Comment: you don't ng-value..  ng-model handle that task

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi How to write the controller for that..??

Comment: you don't need to write anything for that just assign that valu in model you input will automically get updated.

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Ok.I wiil try it..